# how to implement ilu preconditioner for lsqr in python?

Tags: least-squares, preconditioning

I am solving a least squares problem. Using lsqr is relatively slow. Is there a way to add a right preconditioner for lsqr?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html
Here no option to directly use a preconditioner.

Not sure how to define a linear operator for A @ (LU)^{-1} and its transpose.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a question better suited for the SciPy forums.

Comment: Thanks. I will post it on scipy forum too.